# Batch Class - Performance Optimization

Tags: batch, files, performance

I have a batch class which converts attachments to Files for old records in the system.

We are running with batch size of 20 to 25 for the attachments to convert to Files but the conversion process is running for 48 hours for 200000+ Records using a single batch and in some sandboxes the batch query locator expires after 48 hours.

Is there any way to make the batch class run faster for converting attachments to Files.

The main issue with batch size is due to heap size in execute method caused by mapping attachment body to file(content version) body.

Added relevant code for illustration:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
           return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, ParentId, Name, Description, OwnerId, Body, BodyLength FROM Attachment WHERE Parent.Type =: this.objName order by createddate desc]);
   
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Attachment> attachements){
        
    //To map Attachment Id with ContentVersion record
    Map<Id,ContentVersion> attachmentCVs = new Map<Id,ContentVersion>();
    
    //Map ---> Attachement - Attachment Parent Id 
    Map<Id,Id> attachementParentIds = new Map<Id,Id>();
    
    List<ContentVersion> lstCV = new List<ContentVersion>();
    
    for(Attachment att : attachements){
        if(att.BodyLength > 0){
            ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
            cv.ContentLocation = 'S';                   
            cv.Origin = 'C';
            cv.VersionData = att.Body;
            cv.OwnerId = att.OwnerId;
            cv.createdById = att.OwnerId;
            cv.Title = att.Name;
            cv.PathOnClient = att.Name;
            
            lstCV.add(cv); 
            attachmentCVs.put(att.Id,cv);
            attachementParentIds.put(att.Id,att.ParentId); 
        }
    }
    
    attachements.clear();
    attachmentsToBeRemoved.clear();
    
    //Insert the content versions from attachment data
    if(lstCV.size() > 0) {
        Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(lstCV, false);
    }
           
    lstCV.clear();
    
 
}
```

Comment: I have done this using magicmover app. In your case, The strategy to do this would be dividing the records for running multiple batch instead of just once.  It would be easy for community if you can add some minimal required code to see if there is any space for optimization.

Comment: @sanketkumar - added code for illustration.

Comment: the `clear` statements are all unnecessary given the above but without relevant ContentDocumentLink creation, these files will not be linked to their original parent record

Comment: @RedDevil How are you relating the file to the parent record? are you having a separate dml for that?

Comment: @cropredy - i  have only put those parts of code relevant for this question. we do have code to insert contentdocumentlink

Comment: perhaps it is the CDL creation that is slowing down the whole job; that said MagicMover is worth exploring